# Prepopulate Reform with GET vars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reform, trailblazer

How can you prepopulate a Reform form object with variables from the query string?

I understand how to call `prepopulate!` but how do I access a variable on the URL from within the Reform contract?

For example:

```
/example/new?lang=en

property :language, virtual: true, prepopulator: ->(*) { ??? }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow the docs on [Trailblazer GitHub](https://github.com/trailblazer/reform#setup):

```
class AlbumsController
  def new
    @form = AlbumForm.new(Album.new)
  end
```

should be:

```
class AlbumsController
  def new
    @form = AlbumForm.new(Album.new(language: params[:lang]))
  end
```